# Easiest way to export board info in embedded linux

Tags: embedded-linux

So I'm look at sysfs for this. I'm looking at making a module/daemon that can read i2c devices and a couple of other things and export information in the filesystem for our main application.

For instance one of our io expanders is used as a board id, its a tca7408 but I don't need a GPIO interface to it. I just need to read it as an input and export the 0xXX number as an ID for userspace applications.

Just to add to this... is there a way to add custom data to sysfs? Or export application data to files similar to the functionality of sysfs?

Answer (score 0):

If all of your devices are on i2c I would recommend creating a library with an easy to use API, things such as:

BoardId_t getBoardId();

Then you can hide all the i2c details in the library and reuse it where needed.

http://elinux.org/Interfacing_with_I2C_Devices

I tend to only write device drivers for things that actually NEED device drivers, in this case i2c already has a device driver so you can just use it. This will make your code easier to port to different versions of the linux kernel, and even different operating systems, and there is no need to mess with sysfs either.

Comment: Well there are many i2c devices that have modules that add attributes to the sysfs. I'd prefer to use that method. I don't really care about porting the code, that just isn't going to happen often enough to matter.

What I do find useful though is being able to just open a file from different applications and easily read in the ID. Or cat it out and use it in scripts.